# create user with fixture and use id in @valid_attrs in phoenix controller test

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm very new to phoenix and elixir so thank you for your help and corrections!

I'm trying to use a fixture to create a user and user their id for the @valid_attrs and @update_attrs. However I'm not sure how to get access to the user created by the fixture in the describe block.

```
  describe "my test" do
    alias MyApp.Context.Module
    user = user_fixture()
    @valid_attrs %{name: "some name", user_id: user.id}
    @update_attrs %{name: "some updated name", user_id: user.id}
    @invalid_attrs %{name: nil, user_id: nil}
    ...
  end
```

However when I run `mix test` for the above I get

```
== Compilation error in file test/little_things/character_test.exs ==
** (DBConnection.OwnershipError) cannot find ownership process for #PID<0.410.0>.
```

My other tests successfully use the user_fixture in the setup method

```
   describe "another example test" do
    setup do
     %{user: user_fixture()}
    end
    test "example test using setup", %{user: user} do
      IO.puts(user.id) # This will print the user id
    end
  end
```

However I find it overly verbose to write, and would like to pre-define valid_attrs that I can use throughout my tests without having to pass the value in using the second param in test/2

How can I use the user variable in @valid_attrs and @updated_attrs? or is there another more DRY approach I can take?

Answer (score 2):

[`ExUnit.Case.describe/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ex_unit/ExUnit.Case.html?#describe/2) might have its own `setup/1` callback, so the below should work.

```rb
describe "my test" do
  setup do
    user = user_fixture()
    [
      user: user,
      valid_attrs: %{name: "some name", user_id: user.id},
      update_attrs: %{name: "some updated name", user_id: user.id},
      invalid_attrs: %{name: nil, user_id: nil}
    ]
  end

  test "foo", %{user: user, valid_attrs: valid_attrs, ...} do
    ...
```

To DRY, one might put the initialization into a separate private function (`defp fixt_user, do: ...`) and pass it to `setup/1` as

```rb
  setup [:fixt_user]
```

Comment: thank you for your help!
I think this still requires writing

`test "example test using valid_attrs", %{valid_attrs: valid_attrs} do`

am I correct?

I'm hoping to be able to write

`test "example test using valid_attrs" do`

because it's less verbose - using the setup above the describe worked fine, see my first answer

Comment: `test/2` has its own scope (even worse, it runs in its own process,) so why would you expect it to have access to variables from other randomly chosen scopes?

Comment: I'm coming from a JS background so forgive me if I'm wrong here - though I think I'm correct because the test passes.

the test block still gets access to the valid_attrs variable as the second param regardless of if the setup method is above the describe block or inside the describe block.

Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: and the test block can get access to the @valid_attrs variable because it's from a higher scope, the problem is that I can't use the user_fixture inside the @valid_attrs definition. but I could do `@valid_attrs %{gender: "some gender", name: "some name", user_id: 0}` and it works fine (but isn't the actual user_id)

Comment: Frankly, I am completely lost :) `setup/2` inside `describe` block injects values to the context **available within this `describe` block only**. `setup/2` on module level, injects it to all the tests in the module. Your question was how to declare them within the scope of `describe`—that I answered. In comments you asked how to avoid the necessity to receive the context explicitly—that’s impossible due to scoping issues.

Comment: “test block can get access to the `@valid_attrs` variable because it's from a higher scope”— `@valid_attrs` is a module attribute, not a variable. It’s being processed and then discarded during compile time, it does not even exist in runtime.

Comment: More about module attributes:  https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html?#module-custom-attributes

Comment: Ah! I think I understand you better now. I should word my question better - I will edit. I'm not concerned about scope within the describe block or outside the describe block. my goal is to use the user variable in the definition of the @valid_attrs module because the syntax is cleaner.

I'm new so if there's no way to do that then maybe I already have the best answer of using the setup/2 like you said. thanks for helping me learn!

Answer (score 1):

I still haven't found a solution to the original question, but I have found a workaround using setup.

If anyone knows how to answer the original question I would really appreciate it! Though this works for now I think the syntax is still overly verbose

```
setup do
  user = user_fixture()
  %{
    valid_attrs: %{name: "some name", user_id: user.id}
  }
end

test "my test", %{valid_attrs: valid_attrs} do
   assert {:ok, %Pet{} = pet} = Character.create_pet(valid_attrs)
   assert pet.name == "some name"
end
```

I've edited the example to make it more clear why I want the user_id as a key in valid_attrs

Comment: I am not sure how is it a workaround; with this code you might simply return `%{user: user_fixture()}` from `setup/1`, receive it as the second argument in `test/2`, and use `user.id` directly.

Comment: valid point - it's not the best workaround. but it does avoid having to recreate valid_attrs over and over again -> or using Map.merge or something with valid_attrs and user.id

Comment: I'm not showing the full code to avoid complexity, but in my actual code I need to pass the valid_attrs as the only parameter of a method. I've edited the example to make it more clear